# VMWare Workstation - vmware-authdla -Anyone know why this is needed?

Tags: networking, vmware

I noticed that the port 902 on my ubuntu work station is opened and used by vmware-authdla,
 what the point of this service and how to disable it?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Answered [here](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/531803).

Comment: @Ramdound I'm using  ubuntu,

Comment: @UserXD You should edit your question and provide the necessary clarification.

Comment: Are you sure it's called `vmware-authdla` and not just `vmware-authd`?

Comment: yeah, I've just copied and pasted the name from the command line. and after removing the sharing machine option, it didn't stooped until I made a reboot for my computer. It looks like I had a bug.

Comment: Oh, I think the process is actually `vmware-authdlauncher` and that it got truncated in whatever you were using to list it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what the point of this service and how to disable it?

The service is connected to the remote shared VM feature of VMWare Workstation 8+

> You can share virtual machines with remote users in this version of Workstation. When you install VMware Workstation 8.x and later, virtual machine sharing and remote access are enabled by default. This feature is called VMware Workstation Server, and it starts when the host system starts.
>
> A shared virtual machine can be accessed remotely by other instances of Workstation 8.x and later. Working remotely, you can create a new shared virtual machine, convert a standard virtual machine, or create a shared virtual machine clone of a standard virtual machine to the Server where the VMware Host Agent service manages them.

[Source](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2005585)

Comment: I've all ready disabled the shared host which closed the vmwar-hostd service but the vmware-authdla is still running,

Comment: This is the authentication service for the remote VM feature.  I would try stopping the service manually

Comment: I did, and I used the kill command and it works well but I'm trying to find a way to stop it once for all without trying to kill it each time manually

Comment: I had a bug in my os and a restart was needed to solve it once the shared host is disabled. Thank you for you help.

Comment: `vmware-authd` is also used to reconnect to headless local VMs.

Comment: @jamesdlin - Which is unrelated to the author's problem

Comment: @jamesdlin but does vmware-authd requires listing to the network even if I disabled the network remote access ? ( anyway It's good to know what I does )

Comment: @UserXD As I said, even if you disable network remote access, it's still used for reconnecting to headless VMs that you run locally.  But in that case, it probably ought to bind only to localhost connections (if it isn't already).

Comment: @jamesdlin It looks like that the authdla still listing to my network on the port 902! :-/